Serve static images from a specific folder using NestJs
I try to get the images from a specific folder from my project, using this configuration according NestJs documentation:
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    AuthenticationModule,
    PrismaModule,
    UserModule,
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '/uploads'),
      serveRoot: '/uploads',
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

Inside uploads folder i have an image called: test.jpg. Using this confirguration i expect when i use this link: http://localhost:3000/uploads/test.jpg to open the image in the browser, but i get:
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\nest js authentication\\auth\\dist\\uploads\\index.html'"
}

My folder structure is similar to this:
├── src
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── ...
├── uploads
│   ├── test.jpg
│   └── ...

Question: How to get the image on UI using the link above and where is the issue?

I found where is the issue. By default NestJs is looking for dist folder. To avoid the issue i need this configuration:
 ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '..', '/uploads'),
      serveRoot: '/uploads',
 }),

